# Listening to multiple subscriptions in different azure service bus namespaces

Tags: nservicebus

I have a nservicebus based endpoint which is hosted on azure as a worker role. We use ASB as the transport and this is a receiveonly endpoint. We are trying to see if there is a option to listen to an event that can be sent from two different namespaces. For reasons of High Availability, the event publisher will publish events in ASB namespace1 if its up and running in region 1 else in ASB namespace 2. The receiver needs to listen to both the ASB subscriptions. Is this possible to achieve with INamespacePartitioningStrategy ?

Answer (score 1):

The [FailOverNamespacePartitioning](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/multiple-namespaces-support#fail-over-namespace-partitioning) strategy can be used to do what you describe.

In this strategy both namespaces have the same entities and the endpoint will setup receivers on both namespaces as well. When sending the endpoint will attempt to use the primary namespace and on failure will send using the secondary namespace.

At the time of this answer there is [a bug in our NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus 7.0 implementation](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureServiceBus/issues/406) that prevents the fail over from happening. We are working on a hotfix now.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that approach and i have raised that bug. looks a promising approach